# What is the Grammatical mistakes in "The pity is that no sooner he had left the place than the fire broke out"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrase-usage

What is/are the Grammatical mistakes in "The pity is that no sooner he had left the place than the fire broke out" ?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Unfortunately proof-reading is [explicitly off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Proofreading questions can come in many forms: "Help me fix this", "What's wrong with this", "Are there any mistakes", Which is correct", but they all involve reading a specific text and won't really help anyone else. **Please identify what you're particularly concerned about, and edit the question to indicate that.** It's possible, of course, that there's already a question for it, which searching the site may well find.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this would be rendered:

"The pity is that no sooner *had he* left the place than the fire broke out"

Comment: Yes the helping verb "had" should be before the subject "he". But the use of 2nd form of leave "left" is correct here ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 2nd form here. It's actually the past participle of *"leave"*, and not the past tense of *"leave"*. However, since the conjugation is *leave, left, left*, these two words are the same.

Answer (score -1):

> No sooner had he left the place, a fire broke out.